# Ошибка VCS Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

При открытии проекта первый раз во всплывающем справа вверху интерфейса окне с предложением указания пути (*VCS*) была выбрана кнопка `Add path` (что у двух из трёх компьютеров нормально включило вкладку `Version control` и функция заработала).

На третьем же ПК выдало следующее:

> Error updating changes fatal: unable to access 'C:\Users\/.config/git/config': Invalid argument  during executing git -c core.quotepath=false tag -l

Насколько знаю, настройки шли параллельно на трёх машинах (и две нормально работают).

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `unable to access` - видимо в этом